# RTI DDS Configuration File

Tags: xml, data-distribution-service

After setting up my `*.xml` configuration file. I am getting the following 2 identical exceptions: `RTIRecorderModel_lookupType@493: Failed to find type`.

The two types are:

```
RTI::RecordingService::Administration

RTI::PlaybackService::Administration::CommandRequest
```

What file do I include to solve these exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote administration types for all the different infrastructure services in RTI Connext DDS (including RTI Record and RTI Replay) are provided in IDL format under:

```
<rti_installation_directory>/resource/idl
```

In your case:

- The `RTI::RecordingService::Administration` type is defined in `<rti_installation_directory>/resource/idl/rtirecord.idl`.
- The `RTI::PlaybackService::Administration::CommandRequest` type is defined in `<rti_installation_directory>/resource/idl/rtireplay.idl`.

You can convert these IDL files into XML format using the `rtiddsgen` command line tool as follows:

```
$ rtiddsgen -convertToXml <rti_install_dir>/resource/idl/rtirecord.idl  -d .
$ rtiddsgen -convertToXml <rti_install_dir>/resource/idl/rtireplay.idl  -d .
```

That will generate two equivalent XML files in your working directory named `rtirecord.xml` and `rtireplay.xml`. You can include these files in your XML file using the `<include file="">` tag within your types definition:

```
<dds>
  ...
  <types>
    ...
    <include file="rtirecord.xml"/>
    <include file="rtireplay.xml"/>
    ...
  </types>
</dds>
```

**Note:** The paths aforementioned apply to RTI Connext DDS 5.2.0 and above. If you are using an earlier version of RTI Connext DDS, the path to the IDL files is `<rti_install_dir>/RTI_Recording_Service_<version>/resource/idl`.